# Netbeans custom bean issue

Tags: netbeans, javabeans

I'm trying to put a simple bean into the palette of the GUI builder in netbeans. It works perfectly on my PC but when I try to do it on my laptop (starting from scratch, exactly same code and method as on PC), it will not show on the palette.
In the palette manager it also adds the extension .palette_item, which it doesn't do on my PC.
I originally thought the issue was to do with having the newer version of netbeans on my laptop, however after downgrading to the same version is still bringing up the same issue.

This is netbeans version 7.0.1 I am currently using on both machines.

Comment: Hi, do you have the same lib on the two projects?

Comment: Started them both from scratch exactly the same way. Tried originally on my laptop but it didn't work, so just gave it a go on my PC, and it worked fine. There doesn't appear to be any reason it's not working.

Using JDK 1.7

Comment: Update: I seem to be able to drag the .java file from the projects window directly to the layout the way the bean should work... but really this is a workaround and not how it should be done, the issue still remains!